# What's the point of visiting one's parents gravesite

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, cemetery-grave

I am looking for Torah sources on the benefits of visiting parents' gravesite for the deceased or for the visitors.

Comment: Benefit of praying at a gravesite, not specifically parent's: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.4?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.581.27&lang2=he

Comment: Reasons to visit a graveyard (on a public fast day) other than prayer: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.559.10?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.559.41&lang2=he

Comment: Kibbud Av v’Eim, perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

One reason is that it greatly benefits the souls of the deceased.

In the sefer [Pnei Baruch, siman 37, os alef](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47632&st=&pgnum=420&hilite=) it writes:

> ויש הנאה למתים שבניהם ואוהביהם ילכו על קבריהם להתפלל עליהם ולבקש טובה לנשמתם
>
> And there is a benefit for the dead that their children and and those that love them will go to their graves to pray for them and to seek good for their soul.

In the footnote it explains further that the proof for this is that Barzilai the Gileadi states in [II Shmuel 19:38](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.19.38?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> יָֽשָׁב־נָ֤א עַבְדְּךָ֙ **וְאָמֻ֣ת בְּעִירִ֔י עִ֛ם קֶ֥בֶר אָבִ֖י וְאִמִּ֑י** וְהִנֵּ֣ה ׀ עַבְדְּךָ֣ כִמְהָ֗ם יַֽעֲבֹר֙ עִם־אֲדֹנִ֣י הַמֶּ֔לֶךְ וַעֲשֵׂה־ל֕וֹ אֵ֥ת אֲשֶׁר־ט֖וֹב בְּעֵינֶֽיךָ׃ (ס)
>
> Let your servant go back, **and let me die in my own town, near the graves of my father and mother**. But here is your servant Chimham; let him cross with my lord the king, and do for him as you see fit.”

The request being, so that his relatives can prostrate themselves on his grave.

Indeed this case is brought in the [Sefer Chasidim 450](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Chasidim.450.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) which writes:

> ברזילי הגלעדי אמר אמות בעירי כי הנייה יש למתים שאוהביהם הולכים על קבריהם ומבקשים לנשמתן טובה ומטיבים להם באותו עולם וגם כשמבקשים מהם הם מתפללים על החיים וכלב בן יפונה נשתטח על קברי אבות...
>
> Barzilai the Gileadi said "let me die in my own town" because there is benefit for the dead when those that love them go to their graves and ask for their soul a good thing and to bring benefit for themselves in the world, and also when they ask from them , they pray for life, and (this is like) Calev son of Yefunah who prostrated himself on the graves of his forefathers (i.e. he went to Chevron to daven to his forefathers that he not be swayed by the other meraglim - refer to [Rashi on Bamidbar 13:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.13.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.13.22.1&lang2=bi))...

---

**EDIT**

I found on this site [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-31-the-laws-of-a-cemetery-and-its-visitation/#_ftnref14) the first point I brought plus three others. The other three points are as follows:

> 2. **So the deceased intervenes on one’s behalf**: <sup>1</sup>Another reason for visiting graves is in order to inform the soul of any issues that one may be facing and have them pray one one’s behalf. [The Zohar<sup>2</sup> states as follows: When one visits a grave to beseech him about a certain problem, the Nefesh of the deceased goes and awakens the Ruach of the deceased, which then goes and awakens the Neshamah of the deceased, and effects that Hashem have mercy on the world.]
> 3. **Teshuvah**: <sup>3</sup>Another reason for visiting graves is in order to arouse oneself in Teshuvah, as while one is by a grave he remembers the day of death, and how his evil ways will lead to the same outcome as those buried there.
> 4. **Request forgiveness from the deceased**: <sup>4</sup>One who sinned against the deceased is to visit his grave and request forgiveness from him, saying “I have sinned against the G-d of Israel, and this individual who I sinned against.” The following order is practiced: If the grave is within a three Parsa<sup>5</sup> distance, one is required to go barefoot to the grave together with ten other people and ask forgiveness from the deceased. If the grave of the person is further than a three Parsa distance, one may send a messenger together with another ten people, to the grave to ask forgiveness from the deceased. <sup>6</sup>

---

> <sup>1</sup> [Taanis 16a](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.16a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) “In order so they pray on our behalf”; [M”A 579:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.579.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [559:15 in name of Shelah](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.559.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); Zohar Acharei Mos 71a and Terumah p. 141b [brought next]; [Sefer Chassidim 450](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Chasidim.405.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) “In addition, when asked, the souls in heaven pray on behalf of those alive.”; Bach Y.D. 217 “One may Daven by the grave of one’s forefathers to be saved from punishment in their merit”; Drashos Maharil; [Elya Raba 581:39](https://www.sefaria.org/Eliyah_Rabbah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.39?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Levush 579](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14585&st=&pgnum=201&hilite=); Peri Megadim 581:16; [Machatzis Hashekel 581:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Machatzit_HaShekel_on_Orach_Chayim.581.16.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); M”E 581:50; [Kitzur SHU”A 128:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.128.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [M”B 581:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.581.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Kaf Hachaim 581:95](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.95.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [98](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.98.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Minchas Elazar 1:68](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10155&st=&pgnum=172&hilite=) [brings many proofs from Midrashim; Talmud; Zohar]; Alef Hamagen 581:113; [Minchas Yitzchak 8:53](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1600&st=&pgnum=403&hilite=); Piskeiy Teshuvos 581:21; Maharam Shick 293 for a list of opinions on this matter
>
> <sup>2</sup> [Zohar Acharei Mos 71a](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.71a?lang=bi); [Terumah p. 141b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.2.141b?lang=bi)
>
> <sup>3</sup> [Michaber 579:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.579.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
>
> <sup>4</sup>[Admur 606:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3385299/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-606-Requirement-to-Appease-One-Another-on-Erev-Yom-Kippur.htm#v5); [Michaber 606:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.606.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Yuma 87a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.87a.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Chagiga 16b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.16b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [22b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.22b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Makos 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.5b.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
>
> <sup>5</sup>Approximately 5 hours of walking.
>
> <sup>6</sup> [Admur ibid](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3385299/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-606-Requirement-to-Appease-One-Another-on-Erev-Yom-Kippur.htm#v5); M”A 606:7; Rashal Yam Shel Shlomo 50

Comment: Just a small issue that may be added to your great answer: Are we required honouring our parent after their death?

Comment: Yes there are lots of sources about honouring parents after their death but it goes beyond the scope of the question - https://outorah.org/p/19716 and http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=2053

Comment: @Kazi definitely yes! Explicit in Kiddushin 31b ת"ר מכבדו בחייו ומכבדו במותו